# Optional variable take action based on its value

Tags: java, functional-programming, option-type

I have a method which takes an Optional parameter and returns a list. I'll populate the list based on whether the Optional parameter is empty or not. What's the most accepted/standard way if any to write the following

> ```
> public List<ProjectDTO> getProjects(Optional<String> analystId) {
>     List<ProjectDTO> projects = new ArrayList<>();
>
>     analystId.ifPresentOrElse(
>             t -> projects.addAll(getProjectsByAnalyst(analystId)),
>             () -> projects.addAll(getAllProjects())
>     );
>
>     return projects;
> }
> ```

This code works, however I was wondering if there's a better way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would not pass an `Optional` as parameter in this case.

In this case, I would code it like

```
var projects = Optional.of("the-analyst-id")
     .map(id -> getProjectsByAnalist(id))
     .orElseGet(()-> getAllProjects());
```

You can optionally wrap that in a function (like you did before).

Method `ifPresentOrElse()` *does not return a value* and is mainly an operator meant for running side effects.

The `.map().orElseGet()` idiom is the similar, but *returns the value*.

Comment: That's a good example of usage of `orElseGet()`! In regard to `Optional` type, it was introduces in JDK for only **one** particular purpose - to be used as a **return type**. Cases when optional is utilized as a parameter or field type isn't considered to be a good practice.